# What is the "extends" keyword in Spider?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype, keyword, spiderlang

[Spider](http://spiderlang.org/) embraces JavaScript prototype OOP by adding 2 keywords: `extends` and `super`.

- What are they?
- What problems do they solve?
- When are they appropriate and when not?

Comment: I don't know specifically what is the Spider implementation is but here is the cofeescript implementation if that helps: http://coffeescript.org/#classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `extends` keyword allows you to inherit an existing object. For example, let's say you have an `Animal` object:

```
fn Animal(name) {
  this.name = name;

  this.walk = fn() {
    console.log('\(name) is walking...');
  };
}

Animal.prototype.getLegs = fn() {
  return 4;
};
```

You can now create another object that inherits `Animal` using the extends keyword:

```
fn Spider(name)
  extends Animal(name) {

}

Spider.prototype.getLegs = fn() {
  return 8;
};
```

When you create a new `Spider` object, you'll automatically have your `walk` method because `Spider` extends `Animal`.

```
var spider = new Spider("Skitter the Spider");
spider.walk();
```

Spider (the language) also provides the `super` keyword which allows you to easily access the object you are extending. For example:

```
Spider.prototype.getLegs = fn() {
  return super.getLegs() + 4; 
};

spider.getLegs(); // => 8
```

---

### Implementation

This code in Spider:

```
fn Spider() extends Animal {}
```

compiles to the following JavaScript:

```
function Spider() {
  Animal.call(this);
}

Spider.prototype = Object.create(Animal);
```